# Invoke <noscript> even with Javascript enabled?

Tags: javascript, noscript

Is it possible to invoke the `<noscript>` element even when JavaScript is enabled? I need to toggle it's visibility for demonstration purposes of what it will look like.

Comment: Why not just disable and then reenable javascript in the browser?

Comment: Just get its contents and put it in a `<div>` on the page

Comment: That doesn't actually show <noscript> working though :/

Comment: @Xotic750 That's not what the OP asked for. They asked if it's possible to toggle its visibility for demonstration purposes.

Comment: No, they ask: Is it possible to invoke the <noscript> element even when JavaScript is enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new `<div>` element with contents from the `<noscript>` and then remove it after demonstration:

```
// to create
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("noscript")[0].innerHTML;
document.body.appendChild(div);

// to remove
document.body.removeChild(div);
```

Comment: That's a bad approach. You're serializing and de-serializing the data, just to move it from one element to another. DOM manipulation methods should be used instead.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas That's not bad approach. That is *not fast* but short approach.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas From what I remember, with JS enabled `noscript`'s contents are text nodes only and not DOM elements.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I see. The entire content of a <noscript> element is represented by *one* *Text* node. In that case, the approach is OK.

Answer (score -1):

```
<noscript>stuff</noscript>
<div id="mydiv"><div>

$('#mydiv').text($('noscript').text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pDBT/